# When we manage transaction by Spring, what will happen when a method name matches two tx:method?

Tags: java, spring

I have read the following code in Spring document. I noticed that the second tx:method matches all method names, so what advice will be applied to the methods names of which match the first tx:method? The first plus the second? Seems ridiculous.
Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

I guess only the first matched one will be applied while the rest matched will be ignored.

```
<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice">
   <tx:attributes>
     <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
     <tx:method name="*"/>
   </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
Means all methods starting with 'get' and transaction settings read-only 
 <tx:method name="*"/>
other methods use the default transaction settings

Comment: Thank you, @GovindParashar. So if a method matches the first tx:method, the second will be ignored. Is it true? In other words, what will happen if we place <tx:method name="*"/> before <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>? Will all the methods, including those starting with 'get', use the default transaction settings?

Comment: Hi, @GovindParashar, I don't know why the character "*" is missing after I posted the  comment.

Comment: I think the order is matter. I haven't tried other way round means default transaction first then the specific transaction